# How do we match a program to an instruction flow in MIPS

Tags: architecture, mips, processor

I am attempting to build a 32-bit MIPS1 processor and going through the material I got a doubt regarding the program counter. Suppose we have a program that does random operations one after the other, in the instruction memory the operations are already specified and have we access them in a specific order (PC+4), wouldn't this cause a problem?

When the program is first started we jump to a specific location in the instruction memory, but still, the following operations are going to be predetermined since we can not write to the instruction memory unit. We will access it with PC+4 every cycle but how can we be sure that this is the operation which is needed by the program?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question, are you asking how can you be sure that the next instruction is the correct one? If so, it's the job of the programmer to put the proper next instruction in the next address accessed by `PC`, whether thats just `PC+4` or a branch target (after a delay slot). Since it's know exactly which address is accessed, the programmer can be sure to know where to put that next instruction. If you're concerned about how the program is totally predetermined, it very well might be, it depends what I put the program runs on (user input for example).

Comment: Thanks for your timely answer. Yes that is the question, but my doubt remains. You said "it's the job of the programmer to put the proper next instruction in the next address accessed by PC" How exactly? The instruction memory can not be written, it has one input coming from PC and one output with the instruction.

Comment: In the Computer Organization book by Hennesy and Patterson it states                "Since the instruction memory only reads, we treat it as combinational logic: the output at any time refl ects the contents of the location specifi ed by the address input, and no read control signal is needed. (We will need to write the instruction memory when we load the program; this is not hard to add, and we ignore it for simplicity.) "                          How can we write to it if it has no write port, also what should be written there, every single instruction/register combination? @Unn

Comment: I think what that book is trying to explain is that instruction memory is frequently only read by the processor and not written to. In real systems, much of a program actually exists in writable memory but many systems do include instruction ROM, read-only memories. The values in these ROMs is written once at during manufacturing or synthesis of the RTL; so cannot change once the design is finalized. So in this case, there is no write port since the processor never can write to the memory during runtime, but the instruction memory is set in synthesis or manufacture.